# Ubuntu 19.10 stuck at logo splash screen after update and recovery-mode also not working

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I had Ubuntu 19.04 in my MSI GL63 and I switched to Intel from Nvidia server settings for battery saving.

Everything was working fine until I decided to switch it back to NVIDIA. It asked me to reboot my system after which I encountered a black screen right after login.

I tried many fixes including purging all Nvidia related files and reinstalling the drivers and system upgrades but nothing worked.

Ubuntu 19.10 had been released and I decided to upgrade from TTY by `CTRL+ALT+F2` hoping it would work. But now I don't even reach the login screen and it is stuck at the Ububtu logo with 5 dots.

I tried running recovery mode but only command line root access works. I even uncommented WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf in vi editor.
I also tried to remove Nvidia drivers by `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
I also edited the GRUB file by adding `nomodeset` and `nomodeset=0` but nothing works.

I have a dual booted system with Windows 10 Pro.

GPU - NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct drivers when you reinstalled nvidia? You can run: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to automatically install the correct version number for your card.

Comment: @mchid I tried that too. I also found out the recommended driver by `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` after which I installed using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440`